# Number of ways of placing $n$ distinguishable balls in $k$ indistiguishable bins where the maximum size of a bin is $m$

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the number of ways of placing $n$ distinguishable balls in $k$ indistinguishable bins is given by the Stirling number of the second kind. But I don't know how to modify it to include the possibility that a bin has a maximum size of $m$ i.e. a bin can't hold more than $m$-balls. At the same time a bin must have at least $1$ ball.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint 1

You should first try to answer the following question : how many ways are there to select $lm$ balls among the $n$ balls and to split these balls in sets of $m$ balls for $l$ different bins ?

#### Hint 2

For the global formula, you should try to build a recurrence formula using the following principle :

- if $M$ is the maximal capacity of the bins, split into several cases depending on how many bins reached full capacity. The remaining bins should therefore be filled with at most $M-1$ balls.
- if $m$ is the minimal capacity of the bins, what are the situations on $n$, $k$, $m$ and $M$ in which the placement is impossible ?